# Recovering a prime from ramification properties

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am thinking about how much information ramification properties hold about the prime numbers.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime number in a number ring $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$. Factor $\mathfrak{p} = \prod_{i = 1}^g \mathfrak{q}_i^{e_i} \mathcal{O}_L$, and write $f_i = [\mathcal{O}_L / \mathfrak{q}_i : \mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}]$. The values $f_i$ are commonly known as the ramification indices. $f_i, e_i$, and $g$ depend on the number field $K$.

1. Can you recover $\mathfrak{p}$ from knowledge of $g$, for each number field $K$?
2. Can you recover $\mathfrak{p}$ from the values of $e_i$, $f_i$, and $g$ for each number field $K$?

If 2 is false, then can I have an example of two primes with the same values of $g$, $e_i$, and $f_i$ for each extension of number fields $L/K$?

Comment: It's hard to even guess what you mean by "dimension." As vector spaces, you always get something of dimension $[K:\mathbf{Q}]$ as a vector space over $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$, which has infinite dimension over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{F}_p^{sep}}$

Comment: But $\mathcal{O}_K \simeq \mathbf{Z}^{[K:\mathbf{Q}]}$, so the number you are considering (which is just a strange way to write $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbf{F}_p} \mathcal{O}_K/p$)  is just the degree and doesn't depend on $p$ at all.

Comment: Yes I realized that earlier today. I just want the number of connected components of $\text{Spec}( \mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p^{sep} )$. There is another way of saying it: it is the number of distinct primes in the factorization of $\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_K$ in the dedekind domain $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Please do not try to write something fancy and get it wrong when very stanard invariants ($e_i$, $f_i$, $g$) are freely available. That's a bad habit. Also, the
 number of connected components of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \overline{\mathbf{F}})$ (why talk about separable closures of perfect fields?) is *not*
the number $g$ of distinct prime factors. For example, if $p$ is unramified, then $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes \overline{\mathbf{F}} = (\overline{\mathbf{F}})^{[K:\mathbf{Q}]}$ regardless of how $p$ factors.

Comment: As to the question, all variations are pretty much trivial. Given two distinct p
rimes $p$ and $q$, you can find a quadratic extension in which $p$ splits  and $q$ is inert. Just choose a quadratic $f(x)$ which has two distinct roots modulo $p$ and is irreducible modulo $q$, and then take the quadratic extension coming from $f(x)$. The same idea works for general number fields.